# Looped insert with foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to insert into the multi-row database table.

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td style="display:none"><input type="text" rows="4" name="teste[]" value="<?php echo $produto8["Id"]; ?>"></td>
<td><textarea rows="4" name="Notas[]" value="<?php echo $produto8["Notas"]; ?>"></textarea></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="EstadoFinal[]"><?php echo $produto8["EstadoFinal"]; ?><option value=<?php echo $ln['Id']; ?>><?php echo $ln['Estado']; ?></option>
<?php        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM raddb.Status WHERE Id IN ('8') ORDER BY Estado ASC";
$qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
echo '<option value="'.$ln['Id'].'">'.$ln['Estado'].'</option>';
}
?>      
</select></td> 
</tr>
```

Data Submission:

```
function inserir_registo8()
{  

    var dadosajax = {
     'Id' : $("input[name^='teste']").val(),
     'Notas' : $("textarea[name^='Notas']").val(),
     'EstadoFinal' : $("select[name^='EstadoFinal']").val()
    };
    console.log(dadosajax);
    $.ajax({
        url: './resolucaooratorio',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        console.log(result);
         $("#spoiler8").load(" #spoiler8 > *");
        }       
    });

}
```

Php:

```
$Id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["Id"]);      
$Notas = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["Notas"]);
$EstadoFinal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["EstadoFinal"]);
$Colaborador1 = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];   
foreach($Id as $value) {                  

    $query = 'UPDATE RegistoOratorio SET Notas= ?, EstadoFinal= ?, Colaborador1= ? WHERE Id = ? '; // ou WHERE id = ?
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Notas[$value], $EstadoFinal[$value], $Colaborador1[$value], $value ); // ou ("si", $hash, $idUsuario)
    $stmt->execute();   

 }
```

But you are not inserting because you do not receive the html values.

I do `console.log (dataajax);` returns this, but does not return in array:

> {Id: "11", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"}

But you should return this:

> {Id: "8", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"} {Id: "9", Notas: "",
>   EstadoFinal: "8"} {Id: "10", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"} {Id: "11",
>   Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"}

**print_r ($ _ POST); Returns:**

```
Array
(
    [Id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 3
            [8] => 7
            [9] => 6
            [10] => 8
            [11] => 5
        )

    [Notas] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
        )

    [EstadoFinal] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: please post the part where you are filling `dataajax`

Comment: @Jbadminton the part that fills in dadosajax is the html I post at the beginning of the question

Comment: Please show id or class of the table the `tr`s are in

Comment: As a secondary point, since you are using prepared statemtents, then `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not needed. The bind_param method will do the escaping automatically. In fact it can actually create problems if you also use real_escape_string, by double-escaping your data.

Comment: `dataajax` does not appear anywhere in your code. Did you mean `dadosajax`?

Comment: @ADyson I think he does, its a bit confusing

Comment: @ADyson  yes, it was a lapse

Comment: Ok. `dadosajax` is a single object containing a single set of values. I don't see any attempt to make it read multiple values. It would need to be an array, for a start. And you realise that jquery's `.val()` will only read the value from the first matched element in the set, even if the selector matches many? It's mentioned in the [first line of the docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/). Anyway, why not just wrap your whole table in a `<form>` and then just [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it? Much simpler. That's usually the best way to collect the data when submitting via AJAX.

Comment: @Adder id or table class ` <table class="table table-responsive" id="employee_table8">`

Comment: Use the prepare only once and then just execute in the loop. That's why it is called prepared statement.

Comment: There's also a logical error in using `$value` in the bind_param (e.g. `$Notas[$value]` because this comes from your IDs. But these may not be sequential, whereas the form field IDs (once you get that working properly via serialize()` will be sequential starting at 0, and this will be the structure used for the POST variables, it will not use the IDs to number the array indexes.

Comment: Bruno check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the value of each element for every row. The way it is you only get the first value. Maybe this will work, untested:

```
function inserir_registo8()
{  
    var Ids = [];
    $("input[name^='teste']").each(function() {Ids.push(this.value)});

    var Notass = [];
    $("textarea[name^='Notas']").each(function() {Notass.push($(this).val())});

    var EstadoFinals = [];
    $("select[name^='EstadoFinal']").each(function() {EstadoFinals.push($(this).val())});

    var dadosajax = {
     'Id[]' : Ids,
     'Notas[]' : Notass,
     'EstadoFinal[]' : EstadoFinals
    };
    console.log(dadosajax);
    $.ajax({
        url: './resolucaooratorio',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        console.log(result);
         $("#spoiler8").load(" #spoiler8 > *");
        }       
    });

}
```

I can help with the PHP side also if you show me with `print_r($_POST);` what is in $POST.

You can process the arrays in $_POST by using an index to iterate over all of them:

```
$Ids = $_POST["Id"];      
$Notass = $_POST["Notas"];
$EstadoFinals = $_POST["EstadoFinal"];
$Colaborador1 = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];   
$count = count($Ids);
for($i = 0; $i<$count; ++$i) {                  
    $value = $Ids[$i];
    $Notas = $Notass[$i];
    $EstadoFinal = $EstadoFinals[$i];
    if(!empty($EstadoFinal)) {
        $query = 'UPDATE RegistoOratorio SET Notas= ?, EstadoFinal= ?, Colaborador1= ? WHERE Id = ? '; // ou WHERE id = ?
        $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Notas, $EstadoFinal, $Colaborador1, $value ); // ou ("si", $hash, $idUsuario)
        $stmt->execute();   
    }
}
```

I added a check whether estadoFinal is empty. It is easier to add in PHP than in the javascript code.

Comment: updated the question with what print_r ($ _ POST); Returns

Comment: In the variable var data ajax should only take the ids that have the state column filled

Answer (score 0):

You should always start by creating an array object at the beginning of your page:

```
var data_array = [];
```

Then inside your loop you can do:

```
$('table tr').each(function (i, row) {
    // reference all the stuff you need first
    var $row = $(row),
        $teste = $row.find("input[name^='teste']"),
        $notas = $row.find("textarea[name^='Notas']"),
        $estadofinal= $row.find("select[name^='EstadoFinal']");
    var dadosajax = {
      'Id' : $teste.val(),
      'Notas' : $notas.val(),
      'EstadoFinal' : $estadofinal.val()
    };
    data_array.push(dadosajax);
)};
```

Thats how you get this object:

```
[{Id: "8", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"}, {Id: "9", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"}, {Id: "10", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"}, {Id: "11", Notas: "", EstadoFinal: "8"}]
```

Comment: yes an array is needed...except you probably ought to show how you'd do a loop to get all the values from each set of inputs. This code will still only produce one object in the array. It's only half the solution

Comment: That's much better. Does jquery serialize it into a structure you'd expect, though? See my last comment on the main thread...there's another issue waiting further down the line too. That might be exacerbated further unless this serializes in a "normal" way (i.e. the same way that `serialize()` or a simple non-ajax postback would do it).

Answer (score 0):

maybe the issue is $stmt->bind_param because $Notas , $EstadoFinal, $Colaborador1, $value, are strings not array

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Notas[$value], $EstadoFinal[$value], $Colaborador1[$value], $value ); // ou ("si", $hash, $idUsuario)
```

moreover your ajax call send to php file only four dinstinc variables, not a multimensional array, so you have to iterate all the fields you want to insert in DB

EXAMPLE:

```
var dadosajax = []

$('table tr').each(function(){
    var tmpdata = {
     'Id' : $(this).find("input[name='teste']").val(),
     'Notas' : $(this).find("textarea[name='Notas']").val(),
     'EstadoFinal' : $(this).find("select[name='EstadoFinal']").val()
    };

dadosajax.push(tmpdata );

});

console.log(dadosajax);
    $.ajax({
        url: './resolucaooratorio',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          $(".error_message").removeClass('hide');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
        console.log(result);
         $("#spoiler8").load(" #spoiler8 > *");
        }       
    });
```